# How to delete N last messages from a specific user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

As the title says, I want to delete the last messages from a specific user (using `discord.js`). For example: `--delete 4 @user`

I've done this until now:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (command == "delete") {
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
      if (args.length > 1) {
        let mentioned = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

        for (let i = 0; i < args[0]; i++) {
          message.channel.fetchMessage(mentioned.id).then(msg => {
            msg.delete()
              .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${mentioned.id}`))
              .catch(console.error);
          }).catch(console.error);
        }

      } else if (args.length < 2) {
        message.channel.fetchMessages()
          .then(function(list) {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args));
          }, function(err) {
            message.channel.send("ERROR: ERROR CLEARING CHANNEL.");
          })

      }
    } else {
      await message.channel.send(noHasPermission);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Java is not javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something such as this may be of user (as per AnIdiotsGuide Purge command)

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
// Parse Amount
const amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])
if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!');
if (!amount && !user) return message.reply('Must specify a user and amount, or just an amount, of messages to purge!');
// Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
message.channel.fetchMessages({
 limit: 100,
}).then((messages) => {
 if (user) {
 const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
 messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
 }
 message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
```

The usage being: `!purge @user 10 , or !purge 25`

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. However, you can explain me a little bit more about how the code works. I'd like to understand perfectly what's happening before using the code.

Comment: So the first half is just your generic purge command with chosen amounts, if you'd like an explanation,  I  can provide @Henrique . The second half, utilizes the discord.js `.filter` function which can be found here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter

Basically what it does is specify your `bulkDelete` so that it only deletes messages that you want.

Comment: Yes, I would like an explanation, specifically in that part: ```const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
 messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);```

Comment: @Henrique This may be difficult to explain if you are not familiar with __ternary operators__, a good reference can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), but basically, its just an easier way to filter the ID of the user that you want to delete the messages of. Basically, I wouldn't worry too much about this, as I am sure you could achieve the same outcome using `if statements`, the main point of this part is the `.filter`, which basically is how you decide whose messages to delete.